# ASP.NET MVC 3 Basic Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, http-status-code-404

Works:

- http://localhost/ApplicationName/Home/Index
- http://localhost/ApplicationName/
- http://localhost/ApplicationName/AnotherController/

404 Error:

- http://localhost/ApplicationName/Home

I have an Index view for my Home controller and an Index action. 
Everything was working fine, then I refactored and changed the application name.
Now only the Home controller won't default to the Index view when the action is left out

Here's my RegisterRoutes in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

Comment: There was an empty folder in the application root named Home. The application was going there first for the view.

Deleted it, problem solved.

Comment: since you solved the problem, you should post that as an answer, then accept it (in a couple days, when you are able to).

Answer (score 0):

There was an empty folder in the application root named Home. The application was going there first for the view. Deleted it, problem solved.